# Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this error,

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

The code was working, but after rebuilding, the code no longer works

[image: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.]

My Code

```vb
Private Sub KodePembelian()
    Dim Rd As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim Cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim bulan As String
    bulan = Format(Now, "MM")
    Dim tahun As String
    tahun = Format(Now, "yy")
    Dim Urutan As String
    Dim Hitung, Cari As String

    Cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM BY_PEMBELIANHEADER WHERE NOPEMBELIAN IN " & "(SELECT MAX (NOPEMBELIAN) FROM BY_PEMBELIANHEADER)", MyConn)
    Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    Rd.Read()
    If Not Rd.HasRows Then
        Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & "000001"
    Else
        Cari = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetString(0), 6)
        If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Rd.GetString(0), 8) <> "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" Then
            Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & "000001"
        Else
            Hitung = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetString(0), 6) + 1
            Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("000000" & Hitung, 6)
        End If
    End If

    Rd.Close()
    txtpo.SelectedText = Urutan
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check if the reader has rows BEFORE calling read?

Comment: If you use `SELECT *` then the columns can be returned in any order. If the column order matters, list the column names instead of using `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the return value is null. you have to call `IsDBNull` to check for null values before calling `GetString` method.

this snippet should fix the problem.

```vb
    Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    Rd.Read()
    If Not Rd.HasRows Then
        Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & "000001"
    Else
        If Rd.IsDBNull(0) Then
            Cari = "default" ' do something if its null
        Else
            Cari =  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetSqlValue(0).ToString(), 6)
        End If
```

**Note : No conversions are performed on GetString method; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.**

[sqldatareader.getstring documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I guess since the exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.` states it is an integer, OP is not getting dbnull. Maybe a combination of [GetFieldType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfieldtype?view=netframework-4.8) and [GetSqlValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlvalue?view=netframework-4.8) would work

Comment: I agree, using GetSqlValue here is a better option. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thank you mr alireza, i just add getsqlvalue(0).tostring in my code

```
 Private Sub KodePembelian()
        Dim Rd As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim Cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim bulan As String
        bulan = Format(Now, "MM")
        Dim tahun As String
        tahun = Format(Now, "yy")
        Dim Urutan As String
        Dim Hitung, Cari As String

        Cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM BY_PEMBELIANHEADER WHERE NOPEMBELIAN IN " & "(SELECT MAX (NOPEMBELIAN) FROM BY_PEMBELIANHEADER)", MyConn)
        Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
        Rd.Read()
        If Not Rd.HasRows Then
            Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & "000001"
        Else
            Cari = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetSqlValue(0).ToString(), 6)
            If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Rd.GetSqlValue(0).ToString(), 8) <> "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" Then
                Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & "000001"
            Else
                Hitung = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Rd.GetSqlValue(0).ToString(), 6) + 1
                Urutan = "PO/" & bulan & tahun & "/" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right("000000" & Hitung, 6)
            End If
        End If

        Rd.Close()
        txtpo.SelectedText = Urutan
    End Sub
```